# Special grouping number for each pairs

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

There is already some part of the question answered here [special-group-number-for-each-combination-of-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48912908/special-group-number-for-each-combination-of-data). In most cases we have pairs and other data values inside the data. What we want to achieve is that number those groups if those pairs exist and number them until the next pairs.

As I concentrated each pairs such as `c("bad","good")` would like to group them and for pairs `c('Veni',"vidi","Vici")` assign unique number `666`.

Here is the example data

```
names <- c(c("bad","good"),1,2,c("good","bad"),111,c("bad","J.James"),c("good","J.James"),333,c("J.James","good"),761,'Veni',"vidi","Vici")

  df <- data.frame(names)
```

Here is the real and general case expected output

```
     names  Group
1      bad    1
2     good    1
3        1    1
4        2    1
5     good    2
6      bad    2
7      111    2
8      bad    3
9  J.James    3
10    good    4
11 J.James    4
12     333    4
13 J.James    5
14    good    5
15     761    5
16    Veni    666
17    vidi    666
18    Vici    666
```

Comment: Why is a new group started on row 10. You treat good and Good as the same term?

Comment: @Frank No Nope. Just typing mistake. So sorry!

Comment: The grouping scheme makes 0 sense to me. Please explain the groups for rows 1:15.

Comment: @Vlo A group cannot contain the same value twice. Row 5 starts a new group because `good` appeared already in the current group; row 13 starts a new group since J.James appeared already in the current group (group 4) ... it seems like it must be done row-by-row and probably quite slowly, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Alexander is the data listed above in your final format? It's very frusterating to try to solve this problem if you're going to change what it looks like every 2 minutes. You've changed what "names" is considerably, with your latest adjustment.

Comment: @Frank I understand your point. yeah unfortunately the real data is like this. and I have been scraching my head how to do that. I was trying something like `cumsum(names=='good|bad')` but no luck as the location of starting value of groups in pairs.

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess Sorry. I just changed the upper case 'Good' to lower case 'good'. It was the only change. Yes it is the final format:)

Comment: I'll be frank, the way you're creating `Group` doesn't make sense. It looks like it's assigned at random. No one here understands how Group 1, 2, 3,4 or 5 are created. We only know how `666` is created.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of akrun's top post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013850/change-value-of-variable-with-dplyr/28013895#28013895

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess The way of creating group is as it says in previous post [Special group number for each combination of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48912908/special-group-number-for-each-combination-of-data#48912908) . If those pairs exist in the rows, assign a group number to them until the next pairs.

Comment: Hm, actually, turns out I don't understand the rule. For group 3, the values are bad and J.James, so I don't know why a new group starts with "good".

Comment: @Frank Because the data exist in that way. Lets say you have data starts with pairs (bad,J.James) and than (good,J.James). It just as it is.

Comment: Ok, I guess I get it now. You can use `z = as.numeric(names); match(z, setdiff(unique(z), c("Veni", "vidi", "Vici", NA)))` where the answerer on your last question had `sequence(nrow(df))` and it should work... if the key thing is whether the name is coercible to numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two approaches which reproduce OP's expected result for the given sample dataset.`

Both work in the same way. First, all "disturbing" rows, i.e., rows which do not contain "valid" names, are skipped and the rows with "valid" names are simply numbered in groups of 2. Second, the rows with exempt names are given the special group number. Finally, the `NA` rows are filled by carrying the last observation forward.

#### `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
names <- c(c("bad","good"),1,2,c("good","bad"),111,c("bad","J.James"),c("good","J.James"),333,c("J.James","good"),761,'Veni',"vidi","Vici")
exempt <- c("Veni", "vidi", "Vici")
data.table(names)[is.na(as.numeric(names)) & !names %in% exempt, 
                  grp := rep(1:.N, each = 2L, length.out = .N)][
                    names %in% exempt, grp := 666L][
                      , grp := zoo::na.locf(grp)][]
```

> ```
>       names grp
>  1:     bad   1
>  2:    good   1
>  3:       1   1
>  4:       2   1
>  5:    good   2
>  6:     bad   2
>  7:     111   2
>  8:     bad   3
>  9: J.James   3
> 10:    good   4
> 11: J.James   4
> 12:     333   4
> 13: J.James   5
> 14:    good   5
> 15:     761   5
> 16:    Veni 666
> 17:    vidi 666
> 18:    Vici 666
> ```

#### `dplyr`/`tidyr`

Here is my attempt to provide a `dplyr`/`tidyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
as_tibble(names) %>% 
  mutate(grp = if_else(is.na(as.numeric(names)) & !names %in% exempt,  
                       rep(1:n(), each = 2L, length.out = n()),
                       if_else(names %in% exempt, 666L, NA_integer_))) %>% 
  tidyr::fill(grp)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 18 x 2
>    value     grp
>    <chr>   <int>
>  1 bad         1
>  2 good        1
>  3 1           1
>  4 2           1
>  5 good        3
>  6 bad         3
>  7 111         3
>  8 bad         4
>  9 J.James     5
> 10 good        5
> 11 J.James     6
> 12 333         6
> 13 J.James     7
> 14 good        7
> 15 761         7
> 16 Veni      666
> 17 vidi      666
> 18 Vici      666
> ```

Comment: I just noticed that the Q was tagged `dplyr` - my apologies. I am much more fluent in `data.table` than in `dplyr`, so this may take a while...

Comment: I managed to provide a `dplyr`/`tidyr` version of `data.table` approach.

Comment: your solution is elegant! and what I was looking for. Excellent!