# Remove groups that contain certain strings

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an issue about removing the groups that contain certain strings in its rows for example if includes `.`. I would like to achive this without breaking the pipeline. I mean without using any `join` function.

The example data

```
vals <- c("good","bad",'ugly',"good","bad.","ugly")

    gr <- gl(2,3)

vals gr
1 good  1
2  bad  1
3 ugly  1
4 good  2
5 bad.  2
6 ugly  2

df <- data.frame(vals,gr)
```

I tried

```
library(dplyr)
        df%>%
          filter(!grepl("\\.",vals))
```

which removes only the row that match the condition. But I want to remove entire `gr 2`.

```
 vals gr
1 good  1
2  bad  1
3 ugly  1
4 good  2
5 ugly  2
```

Comment: This `df <- data.frame(vals,gr)` should be above the first data frame output you show, otherwise it doesn't make sense (not in chronological order). I suggested this edit but reviewers mistakenly thought it changed anything to your post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
df %>% group_by(gr) %>% filter(all(!grepl("\\.",vals)))
```

Comment: @Tjebo The `filter` is operating only on one group at a time, and it enforcing the requirement that all `vals` within the group not contain a period.

Comment: @joran Thanks joran for your elegant solution. By the way regarding the my another post is there any solution yet ?. I tried your last comment but still no luck. all group numbers are different. [special-grouping-number-for-each-pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48913362/special-grouping-number-for-each-pairs)

Comment: @joran I understand the !grepl filter, but I do not understand why 'gr 2' is filtered out. Is this because it evaluates group 1 as TRUE and then group 2 is FALSE??

Comment: @Tjebo No, remember it's operating on each group in isolation. So when the filter is _only_ acting on the observations within each group.

Comment: @joran Ah, the bell rings. Sorry, this took a while to get into my head... oops.. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be using `%in%` operator.

```
df %>% 
 filter(!(gr %in% unique(ifelse(grepl("\\.",vals),gr,NA) )))

#  vals gr
#1 good  1
#2  bad  1
#3 ugly  1
```

Comment: IIUC, the OP has requested to remove the entire group in which the certain string occurs. Your solution does only remove the specific row, the other members of `gr` 2 have not been removed.

Comment: @Uwe Thanks to point it out. I have corrected my mistake. Actually I was working on solution using `mutate` and `mapply` something like `df %>% mutate(InValidGroup = ifelse(mapply(grepl, "\\.",vals),gr,NA) ) %>%
  filter(!(gr %in% unique(InValidGroup))) %>%
  select(-InValidGroup)` and messed up while adding answer. Your ans looks good too.

Answer (score 2):

The OP has requested to remove the entire group when one of the group members contains a certain string in `vals` - *without* breaking the pipe.

The OP explicitely has stated: *I mean without using any `join` function.*

However, I believe using an *anti-join* does not break the pipe:

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(vals, gr) %>% 
  anti_join(., filter(., grepl("\\.",vals)), by = "gr")
```

> ```
>   vals gr
> 1 good  1
> 2  bad  1
> 3 ugly  1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option in `base R` with `subset` and `table`

```
subset(df, gr %in% names(which(!table(gr, grepl("\\.", vals))[,2])))
#  vals gr
#1 good  1
#2  bad  1
#3 ugly  1
```