# Filtering the whole group contains min value

Tags: r, dplyr

I try to filter the group that contains min x value in them. But I would like to keep the entire group.

Similar post in here but not for `min value` filtering
[Remove groups that contain certain strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916215/remove-groups-that-contain-certain-strings)

So I try

```
  df <-data.frame(x=c(250,240,233,250,100,10,250,100,1),gr=gl(3,3))

> df
    x gr
1 250  1
2 240  1
3 233  1
4 250  2
5 100  2
6  10  2
7 250  3
8 100  3
9   1  3

    df%>%
    group_by(gr)%>%
    filter(all(x==min(x)))
```

Returning the empty df. Why ?

the expected output would be

```
    x  gr
7 250  3
8 100  3
9   1  3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should using `any` instead of `all`

```
df%>%group_by(gr)%>%filter(any(x==min(df$x)))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   gr [1]
      x     gr
  <dbl> <fctr>
1   250      3
2   100      3
3     1      3
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R approach could be finding the corresponding `gr` of `min`imum `x` and then filtering the dataframe based on that.

```
df[df$gr %in% df$gr[which.min(df$x)],]

#  x   gr
#7 250  3
#8 100  3
#9   1  3
```

---

Or similar to your and @Wen's approach using `ave`

```
df[ave(df$x, df$gr, FUN = function(i) any(i == min(df$x))) == 1, ]
```